# Implementing Sidebar In Angular 5 With Class Binding

Tags: angular, sidebar

Trying to implement this [side menu demo (original)](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/admin-side-menu) in angular 5 using `ng-bootstrap` is causing me some some trouble.

Everything is working except the user interaction (clicking the hamburger button) which I'm trying to implement using angulars class binding.

Since I use angular I need to replace the logic behind the click from `jQuery` to Angular. Here is the original `jQuery` code:

> ```
>  $('.navbar-nav').toggleClass('slide-in');
>  $('.side-body').toggleClass('body-slide-in');
>  $('#search').removeClass('in').addClass('collapse').slideUp(200);
> ```

I have created a `SidebarComponent` which contains the property `public slideIn: boolean;`

In the view I'm using angular class binding syntax on every element containing the `navbar-nav` class by adding:  `[(class.slide-in)]="slideIn"`

On the `navbar-toggle` button (the hamburger button) I added a binding to the `click` event.

`<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" (click)="navbarToggleClicked()">`

The method in the sidebar:

```
public navbarToggleClicked(): void {
    console.log(this.slideIn); // always undefined
    /* toggling slideIn property, but slideIn is undefined */
 }
```

Why are the booleans undefined and are not initialized whether the class is initially present or not?

How can I implement the `jQuery` code with angular class binding? Why is my approach not working?

**EDIT**
Code of my component (not running - needs ng-bootstrap + font library etc.)
http://plnkr.co/edit/cKROREQkZmUItLkSVLYl?p=info

**UPDATE**
Just got it working - I will post an answer with my implementation in the coming days

Comment: Please add full component *.ts and *.html file.

Comment: you can use angular directives to achieve the same [**refer here**](http://blog.assaf.co/native-slide-toggle-for-angular-2-and-animate/)

Comment: @Aravind ty, but I don't want to build the animations on my own, they are already there - I only need to toggle the classes

Comment: Please add your full code for that

Comment: @DhavalGohel link to relevant code added